# How to cut our raster with bigger buffer?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I would like to cut out the roof from raster file with bigger buffer.

I can cut out the roof but I prefer to cut out the roof with bigger buffer.

Code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import geopandas as gpd


# Read roofs
gdf = gpd.read_file('/home/gis/warstwadotestow.shp')  # Your roofs
roof = gdf.iloc[4]

# Open input raster and write masked (clipped) output raster
with rasterio.open('/home/gis/73642_915777_N-33-72-B-b-2-1.tif') as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [roof['geometry']], crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta
    out_meta.update(
        {
            "driver": "GTiff",
            "height": out_image.shape[1],
            "width": out_image.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
        }
    )
    with rasterio.open('/home/gis/output_raster2.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

And I will get:

[image]

How to cut out with bigger buffer?

Answer (score 3):

You can just buffer your geometry.
This is assuming that your shapefile (and therefore geometry) is in a projected coordinate system as to get the most accurate buffer in meters.

```
#Buffer of 20m
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [roof['geometry'].buffer(20)], crop=True)
```